# Why is there a difference between the results using <button type> and <button id> in HTML/CSS even if I'm using the same variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, types

I am doing a learn Javascript for beginners course on Scrimba.
We have to create a button. Two different implementations, one using `<button type>` and the other using `<button id>` are giving different results.
I am unable to understand what the difference is between type and id. Please help?

Implementation 1 by the tutorial-

```
<button id="increment-btn">INCREMENT</button>
```

This gives a red button [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFMGG.png)

Implementation 2 by me-

```
<button type="increment-btn">INCREMENT</button>
```

This gives a grey button [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLwwA.png)

What's the difference between the way they work?

Thanks!

Comment: ID is a unique name you can give the button. "increment-btn" is not a valid [button type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button). You have type="submit", type="reset"  and type="button" only. ID can be anything, preferably without spaces and not starting with a digit

Comment: Type is used to determine what kind of button it is. There are only [three options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type), `submit`, `reset` and `button`. While ID is used as [unique identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), this is usefull for styling, aria-* attributes and more

Comment: Thanks a lot! using "increment-btn" in type didn't throw up an error so I got confused. But I get the difference now.

Comment: there a specific set of types for buttons, ie submit, reset, button, you can't use any other types for that, ie you can't use custom button types(i guess).

Comment: @Reyno That should be posted as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer. There is no mechanism for converting comments to answers, so I cannot do it for you. You will need to copy your comment into the answer box and then delete your comment.

Comment: @mplungjan That should be posted as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer. There is no mechanism for converting comments to answers, so I cannot do it for you. You will need to copy your comment into the answer box and then delete your comment.